# "Type 'MPI_Status' could not be resolved" in Eclipse Parallel Tools Platform (Kepler)

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, mpi, development-environment

I'm trying to get a development environment going for programming with MPI and C. I had a look around and found Eclipse Parallel Tools Platform.

I am experiencing lots of errors of the form `Type 'MPI_Status' could not be resolved` and other resolution errors from vanilla eclipse-ptp-kepler. I'm on Linux x86_64 (Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS) using the helloworld MPI C example with the Linux GCC Toolchain.

Also perhaps noteworthy: Launching the default "Local C/C++ Application" Run Configuration gives `Launch failed. Binary not found`

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Suggestions about other development environments are welcome if you are unsure of the solution to this problem.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MPI_Status is typically defined in mpi.h, so you'll have to make sure it's in your include path.  The "launch failed" error also suggests that maybe the mpirun, mpiexec or mpicc programs are missing from your executable path.  You might have to either set up an MPI implementation like OpenMPI locally and point PTP to it, or follow the directions here to set up a remote build: http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.ptp.doc.user%2Fhtml%2Ftoc.html

Comment: Thank you very much! All I needed to do was add `/usr/lib/openmpi/include` to my include path in Eclipse via **Project -> Properties -> Paths and Symbols -> Includes tab -> Languages: GNU C -> Add..** then type in `/usr/lib/openmpi/include/` in the location address. :)

Comment: If you're using mpich instead of openmpi, use `/usr/lib/mpich/include/`

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the flag `-fopenmp` to `gcc` to enable OpenMP, don't forget that OpenMP is a technology that needs support from the compiler; on other implementation the flag may vary, check the docs for your compiler.